# How to get open/closed workflow list from Java code in Uber Cadence?

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm working on a project that used Uber Cadence Java Client. How can I get the list of open/closed workflows from the code? I can get it from CLI but not from java code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
WorkflowServiceTChannel cadenceService =
        new WorkflowServiceTChannel(ClientOptions.defaultInstance());

ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest request = new ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
request.setDomain(DOMAIN);
=request.set...;
ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsResponse resp = cadenceService.ListOpenWorkflowExecutions(request);

ListClosedWorkflowExecutionsRequest request = new ListClosedWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
request.setDomain(DOMAIN);
=request.set...;
ListClosedWorkflowExecutionsResponse resp = cadenceService.ListClosedWorkflowExecutions(request);


// If you have advanced visibility
ListWorkflowExecutionsRequest request = new ListWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
request.setDomain(DOMAIN);
=request.setQuery(...);
ListWorkflowExecutionsResponse resp = cadenceService.ListWorkflowExecutions(request);
```

See how the `cadenceService` is used in this [sample](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/517bbd18b3b5f5ff50890ca831abab87ddff5198/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloSearchAttributes.java#L163)

Documentation about [advanced visibility](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/search-workflows/#introduction)

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me, asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393431/uber-cadence-unable-to-get-history-of-workflow-executions-via-java-client
Using the same instance and code, which registers the workflow and a worker.